# PHPExcel Download and JS returns on form.submit

Tags: javascript, php, json, phpexcel

I'm calling a PHP Script to genereta an excel file and then download it on the fly

```
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=iva.xls");
 $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel); 
 $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

After this code I finish with:

```
 $aReturn[]= array('result'=>true);
 exit(json_encode($aReturn));
```

At the first moment I start calling this PHP using a submit button... then (trying to get a progress bar) I decided to call this php using javascript with following code:

```
 $.messager.progress(); 
   var urlProtax="taxes/processtax.php?start=" + cStartDate + '&end='+ cEndDate ;
   $('#taxesForm').form('submit',{
         url: urlProtax,
         onSubmit: function(datt){
             var isValid = $(this).form('validate');
             if (!isValid){                           
                 $.messager.progress('close');                         
             }
             return isValid;
         },
         success: function(jdatos){
             alert('alert data '+ jdatos);
             data = eval('('+jdatos+')');
             if(data[0]['result']===true){
                 $.messager.progress('close');
                 $('#taxesWin').window('close');

                 return true;
             }else{
                 $.messager.progress('close');
                 var iderror = data[0]['error'];
                 $.messager.alert("ERROR (" + iderror +")" , gt.gettext('Unknown Error'), 'error'); 
                 $('#taxesWin').window('close');
             }
         },
         error: function(xhr) {
         alert('Error! Status = ' + xhr.status);}

 });
```

Excel file is being created fine!!! but I never get the json response to close progress bar.

Kind Regards,

Comment: The normal solution to this isn't to try and get a return through javascript, but simply to "link" to the taxes/processtax.php script. As things stand, you're trying to return both the Excel filestream and the json encoded result in a single response; and a single response can't be both application/vnd.ms-excel and application/json at the same time

Comment: but acrros all the web app I call php using ajax call with a progress bar ... taking your recomendation will impact in the way I show a progress bar to app's operator. As I said in the post I've already done this approach.

Comment: In that case I can't help, I've never come across a script that can return multiple content types in a single request before, so I'm completely out of my depth. I simply can't grasp how it can possibly work at all without corrupting the output from PHPExcel.

Answer (score 0):

Excel files are binary, JSON doesn't support binary formats directly. 
You might have better luck if you use an ascii format like CSV

Comment: I don't but ... its possible to 'change' output after php-PHPExcel save method... so I can send just a Return OK trough json encode. Here I have a theoretical doubt... during the use of Header()... after that.. php output is 'dirty' so then I cannot 'came back' with a simple return true with JSON?